# Form for a different model than the view page in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have Results page that contains an signup form. I'm trying to use client-side validation on the email model, but I can't because the model type is different than the type I'm posting.

```
class Results
{
     ... // some results data to display
}

class EmailSignup
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### Results.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.Results
[display results]
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmail", "AnalysisResults", FormMethod.Post))
{
     <fieldset>
     @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.???? )
     </fieldset>
}
```

The type I want the user to submit is EmailSignup, not Results.

Comment: Great question; I have *exactly* the same problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Move the form to a partial view that takes an `EmailSignup` model.

Comment: What would you do if the display of the results were intermingled with the display of the form, forcing you to not use this approach?

Comment: @enash: Take `Func<T, HelperResult>`s as parameters.

Comment: Sorry @SLaks, as parameters to what?

Comment: @enashnash: To the partial view – allowing you to pass inline helpers.  http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html

Comment: This works, but it's an annoying solution because it unnecessarily forces you to use a partial view.  I think Microsoft should update `BeginForm` to optionally take a different model.

Comment: @Jez: That wouldn't be enough; you would need a different `HtmlHelper<TModel>` instance with different validation metadata (and no way to get prior values).  It would be complicated.

Comment: @SLaks Well yeah but some complicated changes are needed anyway.  Even when using a partial for the mini-form to get a different form model, MVC IDs the input fields identically to their model name, so your mini-form's model could have an `string Name`, and your main model could have an `string Name`, and there would be two `input`s on the page with the same ID.

Comment: @Jez: I'm not saying it's not needed; I'm saying it's much less trivial to implement than it sounds.

Comment: Check my solution. You don't have to create a partial view at all.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done quite easily. You just have to do it like this:

```
var contactModel = new ContactModel();
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => contactModel.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => contactModel.Title)
```

The validation works like a charm.

Comment: The generated text box name will be "contactModel.Title", not "Title"

Answer (score 3):

You could create another `HtmlHelper` like this

```
var emailSignupHtml = new HtmlHelper<EmailSignup>(Html.ViewContext, new ViewDataContainer<EmailSignup>(new EmailSignup()));
```

and use it like this

```
@emailSignupHtml.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

For the `ViewDataContainer` I use following helper class

```
public class ViewDataContainer<TModel> : ViewDataDictionary<TModel>, IViewDataContainer
{
   public ViewDataContainer(TModel model) : base (model)
   {
      ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
   }

   public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sigh, this seems outdated now, HtmlHelper takes in many more arguments. But the overall problem still seems unsolved

Answer (score 3):

I have find out 2 more ways

1. Override the `Name` attribute for `TextBoxFor` and set it as the property name.

```
    var formModel = new ForgotPasswordFormModel();
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => formModel.UsernameOrEmail, new { Name = "UsernameOrEmail" })
```

2. Specify the same exact model name as the post method parameter.

```
    var formModel = new ForgotPasswordFormModel();
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "LoginSurface")
    {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => formModel.UsernameOrEmail)
    }
    ...
    public virtual ActionResult ChangePassword(ForgotPasswordFormModel formModel)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can also try @HTML.Action("EmaialSignup")
and your controller will have a Function calling the partial view
if you have to render multiple model bounded View in this view